# __doPostBack added automatically into onclick

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dopostback

I create a button which go as following

```
<input id="myid" type="button" runat="server" value="click" onclick="myfunc()" />
```

After building, i notice that in the source code part it became

```
<input id="myid" type="button" runat="server" value="click" onclick="myfunc() __doPostBack('myid', '')" />
```

`__doPostBack` is added automatically to my code,which prevent my own javascript function from working. I am wondering why this happens because a button on the same page with same structure doesn't suffer from this issue. And if possible how to solve this issue

[Update]

Myfunc() calls my own postback functions which triggers server side function, and I want the serverclick event of this button to be triggered

Comment: The `runat="server"` gives the server free reign to modify the element. Removing that should fix the issue (and may introduce others).

Comment: what's the context of your javascript?  is there extra validation?  is there a server side event on the click?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 myfunc() calls my own postback method that triggers server side events.

Answer (score 0):

The method is added by asp.net to make sure your button is connecting to the server side button event when pressing it.

Remove runat server on the tag to prevent that

```
<input id="myid" type="button" value="click" onclick="myfunc()" />
```

Comment: But how come the other runat="server" buttons are not affected?Is there any patterns that asp.net will add this block of code?

Comment: @JqWang are the other buttons running in the same page?

Comment: `<input id="id2"  type="button" value="click2" onclick="func()" runat="server"/>`

Comment: @JqWang most likely there is a button event registered for myid button and not id2. if you dubbelclick the button in preview, it will create it.